# FullCalendar preencher eventos pelo JSON

Tags: javascript, java, json

Estou colocando o componente FullCalendar na minha aplicação Java. Estou com problemas para carregar os eventos dentro do calendário.

Como faço para ler o json dentro do meu arquivo js?

Segue abaixo o código:

Arquivo JS:

```js
$.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2016-02-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {            
            $("#title").val(calEvent.title);  
            $("#description").val(calEvent.description);
            $("#start").val(calEvent.start);
            Richfaces.showModalPanel('panelCalendar');
        },
        events: "C:/Projetos/Web/ProjetoCalendario/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/wpos/controle/utilidades/WposExibeCalendario",
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if(event.type){          
                element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-"+event.type+"'></i>");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Arquivo `ExibeCalendario.java`:

```
public class WposExibeCalendario extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List l = new ArrayList();

        CalendarDTO c = new CalendarDTO();
        c.setId(1);
        c.setStart("2016-02-20");
        c.setEnd("2016-02-20");
        c.setTitle("Task in Progress");

        CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
        d.setId(2);
        d.setStart("2016-02-21");
        d.setEnd("2016-02-21");
        d.setTitle("Task in Progress1");

        l.add(c);
        l.add(d);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(new Gson().toJson(l));
    }
}
```

Arquivo `CalendarioDTO.java`:

```
package br.com.advpos.entities;

public class CalendarDTO {

    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String start;
    public String end;
    public String color;

    // getters e setters

}
```

Não estou conseguindo buscar dentro do meu js a classe que faz a conversão do js. Podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: `events: 'WposExibeCalendario'` funciona?

Comment: Olá Renan, dessa forma também não funciona. Será que o problema está no caminho ou no JS que não consegue pegar o conteúdo. Coloquei breakpoint na classe WposExibeCalendario mas parece que não entra nela. Acho que deve ser a chamado mesmo que está errado.

Comment: Você quer renderizar o resultado do `GET`, o JSON serializado com as duas tasks, é isso?  Você já tentou fazer uma chamada [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)? Não entendi por que colocou o *path* para o arquivo `WposExibeCalendario`.

Comment: Bruno, estou implementando agora via ajax, mas no componente do FullCalendar ele já reconhece mesmo eu não chamando pelo ajax. Postei minha resposta para melhor entendimento. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O erro aconteceu devido a eu não ter configurado corretamente o arquivo web.xml.

Meu arquivo `web.xml` ficou assim:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>WposExibeCalendario</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>wpos.controle.utilidades.WposExibeCalendario</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>WposExibeCalendario</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/WposExibeCalendario</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

E o arquivo JS ficou assim:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2016-02-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {            
            $("#title").val(calEvent.title);  
            $("#description").val(calEvent.description);
            $("#start").val(calEvent.start);
            Richfaces.showModalPanel('panelCalendar');
        },
        events: "/Wpos_Advice/WposExibeCalendario",
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if(event.type){          
                element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-"+event.type+"'></i>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

O restante ficou igual. Peguei esse exemplo do site: https://mohittare.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/using-fullcalendarwithjava/